# React - How to update state by key value

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm in the process of learning React but something I don't fully understand is the best way to update state when you have a large data structure.  Below is a simplified example of what I'm doing, so in my parent component I am setting the state like so

```
getInitialState: function(){
    return {
        initialItems: [
            {"id": 1, "name": "Apples", "description": "Description"},
            {"id": 2, "name": "Broccoli", "description": "Description"},
            {"id": 3, "name": "Chicken", "description": "Description"},
            {"id": 4, "name": "Duck", "description": "Description"}
        ],
        items: []
    }
},
```

I then have a function in that component to update the description which I pass down to child components using props

```
update_description: function(id, description) {
    var state = this.state.items.map(function(item) {
        return {
            id: item.id,
            name: item.name,
            description: (item.id === id ? description: item.description),
        };
    }, this);

    this.setState({ items: state });
},
```

Then in my render function

```
render: function() {
    return (
        <List items={this.state.items}  update_description={this.update_description} />
    );
}
```

And my child component

```
var List = React.createClass({
  render: function(){
    return (
      <ul className="no-list no-pad items">
      {
        this.props.items.map(function(item) {
            return <ListItem key={item.id} item={item} update_description={this.props.update_description} />
        }, this)
       }
      </ul>
    )  
  }
});
```

This works but it seems very inefficient (especially if you have a large data structure) because the code is looping through all of the items and checking to see if the ID match and if it does it updates the description.  Also with this method if I add another property to each item like "image", I'd then have to remember to update the `update_description` function.

Ideally I want a way of being about to say "Update the description property where the ID is equal to the one I'm passing into the function". Kind of like you do in SQL.

Is this possible?  At the moment I'm only using React but I'm open to using other libraries and tools to help me out.

Comment: Would you be able to share your render function? For me, it seems like the last piece of the puzzle to better understand your end goal.

Comment: @connected_user Added some more code, sorry it's a bit hard as I have lots of child components

Comment: Are you updating the description in terms of a description that the user sees somewhere? Where is the description being viewed by the user?

Answer (score 2):

At an algorithmic level, you're maintaining an unordered array of elements and performing a linear search for a particular element. As you noted, this isn't very efficient. Instead of using an array, you should use a hash table which will allow for amortized constant time lookups. In JavaScript, you can use an object, or alternatively, a [Map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) which was introduced in ES2015 and as such may not be supported by all browsers.

By using the id as the key to the object/Map, in your `update_description()` function you can directly access the element associated with that key. Since those elements are objects in this case, you can modify the `description` property of that particular object. You will still need to call `this.setState({})` in order for React to re-render.

See [setState()](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#setstate) for more info on using `setState()` with mutable data structures.

Answer (score -1):

My answer is not key value, but it is very efficient.
You could just pass the index of item in render function.
I also thought about object with key of id. But you can't make sure the order is what you want when looping.

```
var List = React.createClass({
  render: function(){
    return (
      <ul className="no-list no-pad items">
      {
        this.props.items.map(function(item, index) {
            return <ListItem key={item.id} item={item} index={index} update_description={this.props.update_description} />
        }, this)
       }
      </ul>
    )  
  }
});
```

And pass it to update_description then you can use index to update description.

```
update_description: function(index, description) {
    var items = this.state.items;
    items[index].description = description;
    this.setState({ items: state });
},
```